# how to debug Ionic 4 android app css issues onRstart

Tags: android, ionic4

This ionic 4 app works fine in browser and on most devices, but rarely on some devices(no matter what version of Android) the styles of some elements  change almost invisible when onRestart the app from background. It looks like the following 2 screenshots for two different ionic tabs.

I could not find any clue about this and even not clear how to make this happen for testing.

Any ideas about this or how to debug issue like this?

Thanks and happy new year :p

[image]

[image]

Comment: Connect the app to system via Cable, enable Usb debugging in Phone settings. Open Google chrome and go to 'chrome://inspect/#devices' . Now the device will appear with App widget ID.Click on the inspect menu and inspect the app

Comment: Thanks a lot. Following your reply, we figured out the css issues. Your answer should be the 'answer'.

Comment: Ok. I will post it as an answer. Thank you.Enjoy coding

Answer (score 1):

Connect the app to system via Cable, enable Usb debugging in Phone settings. Open Google chrome and go to 'chrome://inspect/#devices' . Now the device will appear with App widget ID.Click on the inspect menu and inspect the app